# KMM - Proper Usages of Extension Functions on Enums from Shared Module

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an enum in a shared module that I would like to map some icon resource ids to for use in my android module. What is a sensible way to go about this?

- create a new enum in android with the shared enum value as one of its properties?
- create an extension function for the shared enum that maps it's values to icon resource ids?
- other?

This is for a project in which I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

I'm trying to balance two architecture goals: reduce duplicate code and separation among platforms and among business vs ui

Comment: Creating an extension function sounds good to me